# Locating Storyboard Views by code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I've created my view by code but two UICollectionViews. So created them in the Storyboard and need to locate them by code.
This is how I did it:

```
        TopProducts = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: scrollViewHeight + 166, width: viewWidth - 8, height: 120))
    contentScrollView.addSubview(TopProducts)
```

App crashes and this error shows up in the console:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010271526b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010160af41 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102789ba5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
>       3   UIKit                               0x0000000105d14a39 -[UICollectionView initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:] + 81
>       4   UIKit                               0x0000000105d149e2 -[UICollectionView initWithFrame:] + 58
>       5   JahanCo Catalog                     0x0000000100747bfd _T0So16UICollectionViewCABSC6CGRectV5frame_tcfcTO + 77
>       6   JahanCo Catalog                     0x0000000100744f24 _T0So16UICollectionViewCABSC6CGRectV5frame_tcfC + 100
>       7   JahanCo Catalog                     0x00000001007446f0 _T015JahanCo_Catalog9SlideViewC11viewDidLoadyyF + 9936
>       8   JahanCo Catalog                     0x0000000100744fa4 _T015JahanCo_Catalog9SlideViewC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 36
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010542fd93 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000105476cd4 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 68
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000105477010 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 153
>       12  UIKit                               0x0000000105478127 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 841
>       13  UIKit                               0x0000000105479388 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 115
>       14  UIKit                               0x00000001056c26d9 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010536321e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1331
>       16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000103375c92 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000103379d79 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
>       18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000103302851 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 385
>       19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010332e1c2 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
>       20  UIKit                               0x00000001052b11de __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 141
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001026b82ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010269cadb __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 203
>       23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010269c2b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
>       24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010269bb29 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
>       25  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010aa059c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       26  UIKit                               0x00000001052959a4 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       27  JahanCo Catalog                     0x0000000100754ed7 main + 55
>       28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010750f621 start + 1
>       29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: where you have declared TopProducts?

Comment: UICollectionView needs a flowLayout

Comment: you want to change constraints of collectionView added using storyBoard  through code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the way to create **CollectionView** Programatically

```
class GridViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    //to set the scroll direction
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 20
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I set it to horizontal scrolling direction?

Comment: @VahidGR I guess you can use flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

Answer (score 2):

Heres a small code snippet

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cell
    } 
}
```